# Resource cleanup in Linux

Tags: linux, ipc, process-management, resource-cleanup

How can I cleanup all the resources allocated by a process (process A) when it terminates? Process A may allocate resources in another process space when it uses services provided by the other process(A will use IPC to access services offered by another process).

Are there any standard mechanisms/frameworks available for this? I process run on Linux environment.

Thanks,
Den

Answer (score 2):

Some resources are cleaned up automatically.  Memory allocated on the stack or heap, socket and file descriptors, semaphore operations (if you use SEM_UNDO).

For the scenario you're vaguely referring to in your question (using IPC to access services from another process B) you will need to:

1. detect the situation in process B
2. clean up by hand.

A first-principals method to solve #1 would be process B could either poll the presence of process A's PID.  It's obviously not ideal.  A better solution would be to use an IPC method that detects the other side of the connection's disappearance (a TCP socket, for example)

If you drew the parallel between process A and B compared to two computers on a network, a typical solution to this would be that process B would clean up after every API call from process A, or would decay it's connection list and eventually time out and clean up process A's resources if it hasn't heard from process A after a given amount of time.